# What does "Kaos" and "Ophistodpmos" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Here's a passage from ***Women in the Nineteenth Century***, and I wanna know what does "**Kaos**" and "**Ophistodpmos**" mean. Would anybody help me?

> [Footnote: As described by the historians:—
>
> "The temple of Juno is like what the character of Woman should be.    Columns! graceful decorums, attractive yet sheltering.    Porch! noble, inviting aspect of the life.    **Kaos**! receives the worshippers. See here the statue of the Divinity.    **Ophistodpmos**! Sanctuary where the most precious possessions were kept    safe from the hand of the spoiler and the eye of the world."]

Comment: Ophistodpmos may be a misspelling of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opisthodomos

Comment: Kaos may mean Chaos

Comment: I sometimes tell my students that they don't have to understand every word of a reading, especially when the word is clearly very, very unusual, or the meaning is clear in the context. "The temple of Juno ... (this part - this description), (that part - that description) etc ...". Even without finding in a dictionary, Kaos is firstly 'part of a Roman temple' and secondly "the part of a Roman temple where the worshippers gather and the statue can be seen". (Having checked that Juno was a Roman goddess, I'm now wondering why the author used Greek words.)

Comment: @Sydney You're right. But unfortunately, I was translating the book into Chinese, rather than reading it. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ophistodpmos* is clearly a misspelling of [*opisthodomos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opisthodomos), the back room of some ancient Greek temples.

*Kaos* is probably a misspelling of [*naos*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cella), the inner chamber of a Greek temple. It is unlikely that it is a spelling variant of *chaos*, as has been suggested in the comments, because in Ancient Greek κ (k) and χ (ch) represented different phonemes, and because it doesn't seem to fit the context.

Comment: Right. It was recovered from some manuscript so letter "n" will look quite like letter "k".